# In sterling where we can set the max Elements In Memory?

Tags: ibm-sterling

I tried to search it in customer overrides properties file. But we couldn't find a remarkable difference in that. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the value in cacheoverride.xml.